# How to execute script conditionally in oracle?

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, execute-immediate

I have a long DDL data migration script which has 15 transaction blocks. For each block, it takes data from one table and then inserts into another table.

But now I have come across a scenario in which the database does not have that table. In this case my script does not compile even.

What I actually want is to check and return early if the table does not exist. If it does, then only continue further execution.

But the script does not even compiles since it has statement which contains a table name which is non-existent in that particular database.

After some googling, I found that we can use those statements in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE block. I have tried this, but haven't been able to get it compiled.

Here is the block -

```
DECLARE
  V_OBJECT_NAME1 VARCHAR2(50);
   V_STRING VARCHAR2(1000);
  V_CONTINUE  Boolean;  
BEGIN
  V_CONTINUE := true; 
  SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO V_OBJECT_NAME1 FROM USER_TABLES  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OOLD_SFWID_CHG_LOG_HEADER';
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    V_CONTINUE := false;


IF V_CONTINUE then
   --scubbber code
   V_STRING := 'DECLARE
   CURSOR C1 IS
          SELECT * FROM OOLD_SFWID_CHG_LOG_HEADER;
   BEGIN
          OPEN C1;
          CLOSE C1;
   END;';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STRING
END IF;
END;
```

Please suggest how can we write it..

Comment: I have no problem to compile your code, could you show us the EXACT error?

Comment: There is a `;` missing after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STRING`.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Thanks :)